# python manage.py inspectdb > models.py dont work in existing mongo database

Tags: python, django, mongodb, djongo

`sample_data` is the name of the mongo collection.
At first, I created a model class named `sample_data` because I thought it will just read what's already existing in my mongodb but the result was... It creates a new collection named `{{MyDjangoAppName}}_sample_data` so I search on google "Integrating Django with a legacy database", then tried it to generate the model for me but unfortunately it replaces my models with the error message and looks like this...

[image]

I added a picture of my terminal with the error message below. Is it about the mongo ObjectId?
How can I exclude the objectId here and generate a new id? Is that possible?

Should I stick on manually creating the models in `models.py` and rename the collection name of the existing database?

What is the right approach for this?

[image]

Comment: As far as I'm aware, none of the packages adding MongoDB support to Django are implementing `inspectdb`.

Comment: aaaah okay thanks for the info sir